# Do Universities go through old assignmnets to check for plagiarism?

Tags: plagiarism

I am new University student, in software engineering program.
I was FALSLY accused in plagiarism in my second semester and it resulted in a 0 on the assignment of course. I believe a student copied my code while on an online study group I initiated, but because I was pregnant and gave birth a couple of days after the accusation, I didn't have it in me to fight it, as I needed to appeal and the whole process would have taken probably a couple of months and I couldn't take the stress.

So I just took the punishment and "admitted" I plagiarized. Needless to say, it was the most stressful, terrifying time in my life, I thought my academic career is over for good. Of course, I learned from my mistake and  I stopped helping people through study sessions all togather as I have my family I need to think about, and as I have two babies and I am exhausted all the time it is very easy for me to not pay attention to things. But since then, I am absolutely traumatized and can't stop trying to think whether or not this might have happened to me before and I just happned to not get caught and the thought about this possibility is absolutly killing me and I find my self up at night thinking about it and it is really starting to destroy my life.

My question is, and it's only an hypothetical question as I only started with the study sessions that semster and stopped immediatly after being accused, what happens if god forbid someone coppied my code in a different course before and we just were not caught for some reason? do universities usually go back to check old submittions for plagiarism?

I am absolutly terrified, so much so that I am considering dropping out. 
I know my fear is not rational but I can't control my thoughts and it's driving me crazy, I need some reasurance. I am terrified to work so hard for my degree, just to have it revoked by the university at a later point.

By the way, I take full responsiblity for my mistake, I realize that I should have never put myself in a position where I was at risk to accidently share my code with another student.

Comment: Please talk to your doctor about post-partum anxiety. This is a condition exacerbated by the hormonal changes due to giving birth. Your post bears many tell-tale markers. Do not worry about old assignments, do worry about getting a mental health screening by a qualified professional.

Comment: Well, my family's future solely depands on me and on finishing my degree, this is why I am so stressed.

Comment: Sure - all the more reason to increase your resources by talking to a professional. When you talk about racing thoughts keeping you from sleeping that is a classic sign of PPA. Dealing with that will decease your exhaustion and increase your ability to be there for your family!

Comment: If there is no assessment offence in the future, you should be fine. As mentioned in below's comment, I recommend actually having your case revisited, once your worst stress has passed. Be careful in future who you work with. You were clearly taken advantage of. There should be a student support centre that can help you. This is part of any good university student service and it is your *right* to use it. Good luck!

Comment: Did this plagiarism charge happen since early to mid March of this year?

Comment: @Buffy why is the time it occurred important? I’m very interested to hear what you think and if there is something I need to know

Comment: Merry, you keep redoing this comment - are you anxious about what she meant? I am not sure what @Buffy meant, but I am guessing that she is just asking because universities saw a HUGE uptick in cheating happening as classes went online because of COVID. It would just be interesting to know what % of those "found" cheating were actually innocent victims like you.

Comment: Yes I am anxious about everything. I don't know what is going on with me, my heart bits fast I feel like I am loosing it. I thought Buffy could have had any idea that could help me in any way as no one else was asking specific questions, although it all happned about 7 months ago, but I was still curious. I saw that Penn state has an online software engineering degree, I may trasnfer to there. I don't think any reassurance at this point will help me. I have a serious problem and I need a fresh start. I feel like just the fact I was accused and it's on my record drives me nuts.

Comment: @Merry, I am sure this comment may get deleted, but everything you are saying points to the fact that you need a mental health evaluation. Thinking about transferring should be done ONLY AFTER you seek professional help. You should exactly like my best friend, and she felt SO much better after she got this treated. She said that she didn't even know how much post-partum anxiety was affecting every single thought she had. It can last for multiple years after children are born. Please get evaluated.

Comment: If you are part of a university in the US, they almost always have free or nearly free options for an evaluation. Look up the name of your university and student mental health services. Or ask your OB/GYN for a referral.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs said: No, don't drop out! Especially if you helped a student that caused you to get that black mark of plagiarism. Your story is very sad, because I am in favour of helping people, but clearly, someone gained and you lost. Personally, I would suggest going to the ombudsperson and explain that, due to the stress of childbirth, you felt under duress and have admitted falsely to plagiarism. People should understand now better how stressful pregnancy is and any self-respecting university should give you a chance of reopening the case. Even if not, look after yourself. Don't drop out!

Comment: Actually, @Dawn, I was concerned about the possible additional stress of childbirth during the pandemic.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just want to make sure I make the right decision. If I transfer, I will loose many credit points and will have wasted a lot of time. Is it really safe for me to sta where I am?

Answer (score 4):

Don’t worry,

Just don’t do it or anything like it again.

You were punished for that infraction and they expect better of you now. As a lecturer I don’t go back through all old submissions as I don’t have time..

Just do your best from now on and don’t give up.

Best wishes.

Comment: Thank you I appreciate it. I will defintly not do this again,  But do you think universities have a department that does that (go through old submissions)?

Comment: @Merry none of the universities I have been at, either as a student or a lecturer, has a department for that but that does not mean it is impossible.

Comment: I've been through 5 universities in my career. None does that. It is difficult as is to catch up with the current workload. If we had to go back and retrospectively check old submissions, we would go crazy. Don't punish yourself anymore.

Answer (score 2):

[Since my comment was well enough liked to be kindly salvaged from a deleted answer by @Dawn, I will expand it to a response]

Please, no, don't drop out!

Especially if it was your help to a student that caused you to be tainted by that black mark of plagiarism.

Your story is very sad, because I am in favour of helping people, but clearly, someone else gained and you lost.

Personally, I would suggest going to the ombudsperson and explain that, due to the stress of childbirth, you felt under duress and have admitted falsely to plagiarism.

In our times, there is so much emphasis on fairness and creating a welcoming environment to all kinds of people in all kinds of situations, so academic services and profs should by now understand better how stressful pregnancy is. Any self-respecting university should give you a chance of reopening the case.

Even if not, basically look after yourself in the future, you should not pay the cost for helping others.

**But, first and foremost, don't drop out! Certainly not for this.**